# JQuery-Ajax doesn't call code behind VB.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, vb.net

I have the following problem:
I want to call the AktualisiereSilomethode from the code behind and it should return a list of strings, but all I get is an error.
It seems like the ajax methode doesn't call the code behind, but I don't know why.
I would be very lucky about some help.
If you need more information or more code, please write me.

My code:
1. Ajax.js

> ```
> //GET-Abfrage der Silos
> function GetSiloListe() {
>     alert("In AJAX Aufruf");
>     $.ajax({
>         type: "POST",
>         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>         url: "Karte.aspx/AktualisiereSilo",
>         //data: "{}", (changed it)
>         dataType: "json",
>         success:function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) { alert("Success " + data); },
>         error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); },
>     });
> }
> ```

2. My call in karte.aspx in the scripttag

> function siloUpdate() {
>                GetSiloListe();
>            }

3. my code behind (karte.aspx.vb)

> 

```
<WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
```

> ```
>      Public Shared Function AktualisiereSilo() As String
>         Dim siloModel As SiloModell = New SiloModell
>         Dim siloList As List(Of SiloModell) = New List(Of SiloModell)
>         Dim Datab As Database = New Database
>         Dim list As String = ""
>         Datab.InitializeDatabase()
>         siloList = Datab.siloListQuery()
>
>         For Each el In siloList
>             list = list + el.longitude + "/" + el.latitude + ";"
>         Next
>         Return list
>     End Function
> ```

Comment: you need to add `WebMethod` attribute to you `AktualisiereSilo` method and make the method `static'. also you need to access the data in you success method using `data.d` since asp.net encapsulates the data in variable `d`

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Web.Services

<WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function AktualisiereSilo() As String
        Dim siloModel As SiloModell = New SiloModell
        Dim siloList As List(Of SiloModell) = New List(Of SiloModell)
        Dim Datab As Database = New Database
        Dim list As String = ""
        Datab.InitializeDatabase()
        siloList = Datab.siloListQuery()
        For Each el In siloList
            list = list + el.longitude + "/" + el.latitude + ";"
        Next
        Return list
End Function
```

---

Because your datatype is Json. 
(dataType: "json")

 So try this to get the values.

```
Public Shared Function AktualisiereSilo() As String
        'Json string
        Return "[{ ""name"": ""guest01"", ""age"": ""29"", ""height"": ""7"" }]"
End Function
```

---

```
function GetSiloListe() {
    alert("In AJAX Aufruf");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/AktualisiereSilo",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data.d);
        var numOfData = data.length; 
        for (var i = 0; i < numOfData; i++) {
              alert(data[i]["name"]);   
              alert(data[i]["age"]);    
              alert(data[i]["height"]); 
        }
        },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); },
    });
}
```

---

You need to make sure that the strings return format is json type.

```
Imports System.Web.Services

<WebMethod()> _
 Public Shared Function AktualisiereSilo() As String
        Dim siloModel As SiloModell = New SiloModell
        Dim siloList As List(Of SiloModell) = New List(Of SiloModell)
        Dim Datab As Database = New Database
        Dim list As String = ""
        Datab.InitializeDatabase()
        siloList = Datab.siloListQuery()
        For Each el In siloList
            list = list + el.longitude + "/" + el.latitude + ";"
        Next
        Return list
End Function
```

Comment: okay, I've tried it but it doesn't work.. I'm just getting the errormessage and not the data.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to add data if you are not sending anything

```
function GetSiloListe() {
    alert("In AJAX Aufruf");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Karte.aspx/AktualisiereSilo",

        dataType: "json",
        success:function (data, textStatus, jQxhr) { alert("Success " + data); },
        error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); },
    });
}
```

and in your VB change it like this

```
<WebMethod()>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Shared Function AktualisiereSilo() As String
        Dim siloModel As SiloModell = New SiloModell
        Dim siloList As List(Of SiloModell) = New List(Of SiloModell)
        Dim Datab As Database = New Database
        Dim list As String = ""
        Datab.InitializeDatabase()
        siloList = Datab.siloListQuery()

        For Each el In siloList
            list = list + el.longitude + "/" + el.latitude + ";"
        Next
        Return list
    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it. But now I'm just getting an error. If I change my ajaxfunction just to type, url, success and error I'm getting the html/scripttext which looks like my Karte.aspx.

Comment: okay please put a debugger at the very start of the function and first test whether you are able to hit the debugger or not

Comment: thank you, I put the debugger at the start of the function and the debugger isn't hit. Maybe it has a problem because I'm working with WebForms? It's the first time I'm working with ajax,jquery and VB.NET...

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to add WebMethod to your method to get required result in http response. When you call `Karte.aspx` it goes through complete life cycle described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Go through [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) and this, i hope it will clear your concepts.

You can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17203/Using-jQuery-for-AJAX-in-ASP-NET) if you dont want webmethod